# How to find the cumulative distribution function of storm durations from a precipitation time series?

Tags: list, plot, time-series, duration, cdf

I have two precipitation time series and I want to plot the empirical cumulative distribution function(CDF) of storm duration for both cases on the same plot. Can I get the storm durations in a list form somehow? And then how to plot the CDF of those storm durations? Thanks

I tried to identify the storm events from the precipitation time series by setting a threshold, but I am not able to proceed.